# Blender 3.0 Geometry Nodes Moss Effect

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

Trying to replicate the moss effect shown in one of the feature videos for the new Blender 3.0 geometry nodes.

The video is title Eevee Atributes and is about half way down [this page](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-0/).

I can get most of it, except for when it comes to changing the material I can't figure out how to get the gradient blend between the vertexes. There's just a hard edge.

I'm guessing there's something going on in group I can see titled 'GE-view_pattern'?

See my efforts below. Ignore all the empty node sockets, I couldn't figure out how to delete them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since it relies on information on the geometry level, you'll need to subdivide your mesh more

Comment: I just tried subdividing more but don't think that's all there is to it. Also it just lags too much before it looks close to being as smooth in the video.

Comment: All good, I figured it out. I needed to capture and output the attribute and then plug it into the Fac of a mix shader to combine the green and grey materials.